# auto switching user with task scheduler in win7

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, taskscheduler, switch-user

I have windows7.
My computer has 2 accounts: `Admin` (with password) and `Guest`(w/o password).

My purpose is to login on Guest account when wakes up from hibernate using task scheduler.

When the computer wakes up from hibernate the status of accounts is as follow:

`Admin`: `Logged on` but `Locked`

`Guest`: `Logged off`

I created task in `Task Scheduler` which wakes up computer from hibernate and run: `%windir%\System32\tsdiscon.exe` - it moves me to the login screen.

Now I'd like to find a way to log in `Guest` account automatically.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can not auto login to another account without a restart.

Create regfile auto-login-guest.reg with this code:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"AutoAdminLogon"="1"
"DefaultUserName"="guest"
"DefaultPassword"=""
```

Create a scheduled task:

```
regedt32 /s "auto-login-guest.reg"
shutdown /r /t 1
```

Regedt32 adds the regfile to the registry silently.  Shutdown restarts in one second and forces the close of all open programs.